# PDFJS is not defined in pdf.worker.js (Backbone+Marionette+pdf.js)

Tags: javascript, pdf, backbone.js, marionette, pdf.js

I want to render a PDF inside a Backbone.js/Marionette View with pdf.js, but PDFJS is not defined **in pdf.worker.js**. It is however defined in the Backbone View itself and also accessible via the console.

*This is the code for the View:*

```
module.exports = PDFView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: require('../../../templates/pdf_frame.hbs'),
    onRender: function(){
        var PDF_PATH = '../../pdf/websummitpitch.pdf';
        var PAGE_NUMBER = 1;
        var PAGE_SCALE = 1.5;
        var SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';

        if (PDFJS) {
            console.log("PDFJS is loaded in Backbone View");
        } else {
            console.log("PDFJS is NOT loaded in Backbone View");
        }

        PDFJS.workerSrc = "/js/pdf.worker.js";
        console.log("workerSrc is set to ", PDFJS.workerSrc);

        // Loading document and page text content
        PDFJS.getDocument({url: PDF_PATH}).then(function (pdfDocument) {
            console.log("get document");

            pdfDocument.getPage(PAGE_NUMBER).then(function (page) {
                console.log("get page");

                var viewport = page.getViewport(PAGE_SCALE);
                page.getTextContent().then(function (textContent) {
                    // building SVG and adding that to the DOM
                    var svg = this.buildSVG(viewport, textContent);

                    // render svg in <canvas id="render"> in template
                    document.getElementById('render').appendChild(svg);
                });
            });
        });
    },
    buildSVG: function(viewport, textContent) {
        // Building SVG with size of the viewport (for simplicity)
        var svg = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg:svg');
        svg.setAttribute('width', viewport.width + 'px');
        svg.setAttribute('height', viewport.height + 'px');
        // items are transformed to have 1px font size
        svg.setAttribute('font-size', 1);

        // processing all items
        textContent.items.forEach(function (textItem) {
            // we have to take in account viewport transform, which incudes scale,
            // rotation and Y-axis flip, and not forgetting to flip text.
            var tx = PDFJS.Util.transform(
                PDFJS.Util.transform(viewport.transform, textItem.transform),
                [1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]);
            var style = textContent.styles[textItem.fontName];
            // adding text element
            var text = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'svg:text');
            text.setAttribute('transform', 'matrix(' + tx.join(' ') + ')');
            text.setAttribute('font-family', style.fontFamily);
            text.textContent = textItem.str;
            svg.appendChild(text);
        });
        return svg;
    }
});
```

*This is the console output:*
[image: console output]
The blue is console input, so PDFJS is accessible via the console.

*This is where the reference error occurs (in pdf.worker.js):*

```
PDFJS.version = '1.0.233';
```

It is one of the very first lines, where the version number is set. However PDFJS seems to be undefined.

*This is my question:*

Why is it not defined? How should I fix this?

Comment: Where do you actually load `pdf.worker.js` (can I see your `define` statement for the module?)

Comment: Also not sure why you are using `module.exports`. For frontend AMD modules follow this format: http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#deffunc Remember that on frontend nothing is synchronous (as far as loading external files).

Comment: Why do I use module.exports? It is pretty standard for a View in backbone/marionette.

This is how the pdf.worker.js should be loaded according to the examples.
PDFJS.workerSrc = "/js/pdf.worker.js";

Do I need to specify a define function? I don't fully grasp the concept and how it could help me here. Tnx:)

Comment: are you using Require.js to load the modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the pdf viewer to work. Instead of using:

```
 PDFJS.workerSrc = "/js/pdf.worker.js";
```

I just disabled the worker like this:

```
 PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
```

Now it magically works. Not sure why though.